# Can we prevent table from update directly but allow update using trigger from another table?

Tags: mysql, database-design, trigger

So, let's say I have 3 tables:

1. `stocks` table, it have columns: `id`, `product_id`, `stock`
2. `sell` table, it have columns: `id`, `product_id`, `qty`
3. `buy` table, it have columns: `id`, `product_id`, `qty`

What I want to do:

- Prevent update `stocks.stock` value directly.
- But allow update `stocks.stock` value by trigger from `buy` or `sell` table.

Is this possible? If it's possible, how? If its impossible, why?

Answer (score 0):

[create trigger](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-trigger.html) has a `definer = {user}` option for this.

You need to ensure that this defined user has `update` access to the `stocks.stock` however the other users only have `select` table access.

[GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) can control access at a table level.

Answer (score 0):

Write Stored Procedure(s) to do buy/sell.  Define it with `SECURITY DEFINER`.  Install the proc as `root` so that it will have access.

Grant `EXECUTE` to the users so they can run the proc.